# Wordpress security on IIS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows, iis, wordpress

We are migrating our WordPress site to an IIS web server. Previously it was hosted on an apache server in a Linux environment.

The site uses All-in-one-wordpress-security plugin (aiowps) for optimizing our security, however, aiowps plugin is only compatible with .htaccess files (used by our current apache / Linux server).

Is there a way to make this plugin use web.config in order to be compatible with IIS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [All In One WP Security & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) is not an _off-topic_ web hosting control panel, but a WordPress plug-in. I think [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better StackExchange site for asking this question. However, I can't directly vote for migration, since ProWebmasters is not in migration options.

Comment: @EsaJokinen the ProWebasters is more oriented around SEO / Sysadmin queries, where as I'm looking for a .htaccess to web.config conversion

Comment: Use a different plugin, there are many to choose from. I don't use any security plugins, I just secure my server properly and keep excellent backups, I haven't had a problem yet.

Comment: @Tim any IIS compatible plugin you'd recommend please?

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend one for IIS. Wordpress on IIS is probably fairly rare, but one should work. Exactly what are you trying to achieve with a security plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use such rules and convert them with IIS [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module.

After installing the module, Microsoft IIS Manager will have a tool for migrating the [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules from your `.htaccess` into IIS `web.config`. From [Importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules):

> 1. Start **IIS Manager**.
> 2. On the left, in the **Connections** pane, select **Default Web Site**.
> 3. On the right, in **Features View**, click **URL Rewrite**.
> 4. On the right, in the **Actions** pane, click **Import Rules**.
> 5. Copy the example mod_rewrite rules above and past them into the **Rewrite rules** text box.
> 6. The **Tree View** tab of the **Converted Rules** box instantly shows the result of the conversion. You can also click the **XML
>      View** tab to see how the rules are stored in the Web.config file.

However, the WordPress plug-in [All In One WP Security & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) is based on modifying the `.htaccess` file i.e. is not designed to be used with IIS. Therefore, you would need to manually convert the rules after every modification. It could be better to find a plug-in that is designed for WP + IIS.